# Testing high power inductors

Tags: inductor, inductance

We are using inductors in 180KVA converter circuits.

To measure the inductance value of the inductor we are following the process of pumping the current up to 300A and voltage up to 30V.

After noting the values of voltage and currents we are calculating the value of inductive reactance and with this we are finding the value of L.  The value of inductances are 5.7 to 6.3 mHenries and 205 to 245 micro Henries.

Is there any other process for measuring the value of an inductors inductance?

Answer (score 2):

You might measure the resonant frequency with a known capacitor, using a spectrum analyser.

One feature of this approach is that you can choose a suitable frequency band by selecting the capacitor, and isolate the measurement circuit from DC or low frequency AC voltages. Any change in inductance due to saturation from DC currents should be measurable this way.